Difference % between 2 columns in Pivot table using Dax measure within Power Pivot
I can't find a formula which calculates the difference % between 2 columns in my pivot table using Power Pivot.
See Data in data model:

See Pivot table where I want to create a measure :

I want to calculate the sum of sales for week 1 in 2024 against the sum of sales for week 1 in 2023 and get the difference %. So in the pivot table above I want to add a column after each week which shows the difference % between the 2 weeks for each week up to week 52.
In a normal Pivot table I would create a calculated field and choose Difference % from.
See below, calculated field in normal pivot table :

How can I recreate this using a Dax formula?

Use CALCULATE() to shift the evaluation context back a week? It's on the DaxPatterns[dot]com website.

Sorry, I couldn't find anything on this website about shifting the evaluation context. Could you please provide a link? Thank you!

If you were to create a measure and add it to the pivot table, you will then have it present in each & every column, which I don't think you want.
If you can live without having the Date column then I would suggest you only have the Week Number column in your Pivot and drop the Year and Week Date columns. And instead create three new Measures for "2024", "2023", "YoY %".
Sales 2024 := CALCULATE(SUM('YourTable'[TOTAL]), 'YourTable'[YEAR] = 2024)

Sales 2023 := CALCULATE(SUM('YourTable'[TOTAL]), 'YourTable'[YEAR] = 2023)

Sales YoY %:= DIVIDE([Sales 2024], [Sales 2023]) - 1

Then add these three new measures to your Values well in your Pivot table.

Welcome back Sam. Have an upvote

Thank you for your answer. This works but unfortunately it is not what I need. The reason why I'm using Power Pivot instead of a normal Pivot table is that I can show the dates not just the week numbers. Looks like what I want to achieve is not possible. Thank you for your time and effort to answer my question.
